# VM Debian Google Cloud Accounts cannot see other account's folder

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, debian, virtual-machine, account

I wanted to ask something regarding Debian Virtual Machine on Google Cloud. So I've set some configurations on my Compute Engine and on my laptop such that I can ssh to the VM from my laptop with `ssh account1@IPAddress` and now I'm logged in as `account1@VM-name $` in my terminal. After doing so, I clone my own GitHub Repo to start my Node.js server (the Node.js server might be unimportant in this case, but the git clone is important to the story line). Then, I decided to disconnect from terminal and decided to do SSH-in-browser method. With that I'm logged in with my email, that is let's say `account2@VM-name $`. However, when I typed `ls`, the GitHub folder is not there. Is this normal with Debian VMs across cloud services such that different accounts cannot see other folders, or is there actually away to share the same files with different "ssh accounts"? Or maybe I should `sudo git clone` such that it is saved in the `root` folder in the VM?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. when you logged using account1@vm-name and cloned your github repo it will be available in **/home/account1** directory.
2. Now when you are logged in now with account2@vm and do ls , it will show details of **/home/account2** and it is obvious nothing is there.

you can use below commands.

sudo cd /home/account1

ls